# Jackson annotation to exclude all fields except those specified

Tags: java, spring, serialization, jackson, annotations

I am currently working on a Sprint Boot project and am using Jackson to handle DTO serialization and deserialization.
I am using the `@JsonIgnoreProperties` annotation to exclude certain fields from the mapped JSON.

However, I have found myself with the issue of selecting only a small number of fields to serialize, for instance in an update DTO or an insert DTO. Right now I have classes which look like this:

```
// Only serialize ClassToSerializeDTO containing "field2".
@JsonIgnoreProperties{"field1", "field3", [...], "field24", "field25"}
public class ClassToSerializeDTO {
    
    Object field1;
    Object field2;
    // ...
    Object field25;

}
```

This requires a bit of too much overthinking that could be easily solved by having an annotation, say `@JsonIgnoreAllExcept`, which does the reciprocal of `@JsonIgnoreProperties`.

```
// This would do the exact same thing, and is much less verbose!
@JsonIgnoreAllExcept(value = {"field2"})
public class ClassToSerializeDTO {
    
    Object field1;
    Object field2;
    // ...
    Object field25;

}
```

Is there a way to achieve this? I have tried extending `@JsonIgnoreProperties`, but have not found a way to do this.

Comment: Can you just use `ignoreUnknown=true`?

Comment: Not really. All the objects I am using `@JsonIgnoreProperties` on are extensions of other DTO objects, which have been marked with the `@Data` lombok annotation, since getters and setters are needed for other uses. I would like to be able to just straight select a number of fields to add to the Json manually, with a similar mechanism to `@JsonIgnoreProperties`.

Comment: I would recommend to have dedicated classes for the JSON representation (which only has the fields we want to serialize), and use a mapper between the JSON-representation and the DTO.

Comment: @Turing85 That could work, but I also need to extend the original DTO classes, as that allows me for a easy conversion from the updateDTO object to the original DTO object,  so this solution unfortunately would not fit my specific needs.

Comment: You cannot have the cake and eat it at the same time. Either segregate the concnern, or live with the long list of exlcudes.